# Scroll DataGridView C# reacomodar un panel (parent)

Tags: c#, .net

tengo un proyecto de reservas de carpas, el sistema esta desarrollado en C#(Windows Forms), estoy intenando lo siguiente:

Tengo un DataGridView que dentro de el, en un rango de celdas tiene un panel dibujado arriba dependiendo si esta o no alquilada la reserva, la imagen es la siguiente:

[image: Hasta aca todo OK:]

El problema ahora viene cuando quiero scrollear, y los paneles no se reacomodan, es decir siguen el scroll del datagridview, un ejemplo es la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahi en la imagen, marco donde deberia quedar el panel, el problema es que cuando voy scrolleando ,los paneles bajan y no se mantienen fijos en el row que los pinte por primera instancia...

Alguno puede ayudarme? Gracias....

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

En esta instancia agrego el panel al datagridview:

```
 private void agregarPanel(int columIndex,
        int rowIndex, int columnIndexHasta, int rowIndexHasta, int cantidadSlots, string clienteNombre,
        int reservaId, int reservaparticionId, int reservaEstado)
    {
        Rectangle coordenada = dgvPrincipalReservas.GetCellDisplayRectangle(columIndex, rowIndex, false);
        int widthCell = coordenada.Width;
        int heightCell = coordenada.Height;
        Rectangle rectanglePinta = new Rectangle(coordenada.X, coordenada.Y, (widthCell * cantidadSlots), heightCell);

        Panel panelAgregar = new Panel();
        dgvPrincipalReservas.Controls.Add(panelAgregar);
        //panelAgregar.Parent = dgvPrincipalReservas;
        if (columIndex > 1)
        {
            Color colorReserva = new Color();
            if (reservaEstado == (int)Reservas_Estados.ESTADOS.LIBRE)
                panelAgregar.BackColor = Color.ForestGreen;
            else if (reservaEstado == (int)Reservas_Estados.ESTADOS.ALQUILADA)
                panelAgregar.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            panelAgregar.Location = new Point(coordenada.X, coordenada.Y);
            panelAgregar.Width = widthCell * cantidadSlots;
            panelAgregar.Height = heightCell;
            panelAgregar.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            panelAgregar.BringToFront();
            panelAgregar.Visible = true;
            //panelAgregar.Tag = $"{rowIndex},{columnIndexHasta}";
            panelAgregar.Name = $"{reservaparticionId}";
            panelAgregar.Tag = $"{coordenada.X},{coordenada.Y}";
            panelAgregar.DragDrop += new DragEventHandler(newLabel_DragDrop);
            panelAgregar.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(newPanel_MouseDown);
            panelAgregar.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(newPanel_MouseMove);
            panelAgregar.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(newPanel_MouseUp);
            panelAgregar.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(newPanel_MouseLeave);

            Label newLabel2 = new Label();
            panelAgregar.Controls.Add(newLabel2);
            newLabel2.Text = $"{reservaId} - {clienteNombre.ToUpper()}";
            newLabel2.Name = $"{reservaparticionId}";
            //newLabel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            newLabel2.AutoSize = true;
            newLabel2.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(newLabel2_MouseClick);
            return;
        }

        panelAgregar.Visible = false;

    }
```

Y actualmente, cada vez que scrolleo quiero que se mantenga el panel en la posicion en la que esta en ese momento, por lo tanto llamo al evento del datagridview "Scroll", que no se si esta bien, si alguno sabe como resolverlo le agradeceria, les dejo el codigo de como estoy haciendolo actualmente:

```
 private void dgvPrincipalReservas_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        string msg = "";
        //Point clientPoint = dgvPrincipalReservas.PointToClient(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y));
        //rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop = dgvPrincipalReservas.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).RowIndex;
        //columnIndexMouseDrop = dgvPrincipalReservas.HitTest(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y).ColumnIndex;
        Console.WriteLine($"{e.NewValue}, {e.OldValue}");
        foreach (Control ct in dgvPrincipalReservas.Controls)
        {

            if(ct.GetType() == typeof(Panel))
            {
               Control controlSender = sender as Control;
               var ct2 = (Panel)ct;
                List<string> tokens = ct2.Tag.ToString().Split(',').ToList();
                Console.WriteLine($"{ct2.Location.X} , {ct2.Location.Y}");
                string nameP = ct2.Name.ToString();
                //Point clientPoint = dgvPrincipalReservas.PointToClient(new Point(ct2.Location.X, ct2.Location.Y));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((dgvPrincipalReservas.HorizontalScrollingOffset - ct2.Location.X), (dgvPrincipalReservas.VerticalScrollingOffset - ct2.Location.Y ));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((ct2.Location.X -dgvPrincipalReservas.Location.X ), ( ct2.Location.Y - dgvPrincipalReservas.Location.Y));
                ct2.Location = new Point((dgvPrincipalReservas.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - ct2.Location.X), (dgvPrincipalReservas.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex - ct2.Location.Y));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((ct2.Location.X - dgvPrincipalReservas.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex ), (ct2.Location.Y - dgvPrincipalReservas.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex ));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((dgvPrincipalReservas.HorizontalScrollingOffset + ct2.Location.X), (dgvPrincipalReservas.VerticalScrollingOffset + ct2.Location.Y));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((dgvPrincipalReservas.HorizontalScrollingOffset), (dgvPrincipalReservas.VerticalScrollingOffset));
                //ct2.Location = new Point((ct2.Location.X ), (vscroll - ct2.Location.Y));

                //ct2.Location.Offset((dgvPrincipalReservas.HorizontalScrollingOffset - ct2.Location.X), (dgvPrincipalReservas.VerticalScrollingOffset - ct2.Location.Y));
            }
        }
       //panelAgregar.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(dgvPrincipalReservas.AutoScrollOffset.X, dgvPrincipalReservas.AutoScrollOffset.Y);
    }
```

Gracias !!!

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta y poner el codigo que has intentado para q se te pueda ayudar

Comment: Ahi esta @Japv , Gracias por el comentario y la sugerencia!